# How to display each block once in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code and I would like to display each block of 10 links in the right environment each time. First 10 lines are displayed correctly but then, the second time first 10 lines are displayed again + second 10 lines and so on. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

I have an object called config which has two more object inside advertisers and env.
The advertisers object has advertisers as properties and each advertiser has locales, hotel_id and partner_id. The env has 3 different environments.

```
for (var prop in config.advertisers) {
  var partner= (`${prop}`);
  var locales_number = config.advertisers[partner].locales.length; 

  var partner_folder = "<br>"+partner + "<br>"
  document.write(partner_folder);

    for (var prop in config.env) 
    {
     var environment = (`${prop}`);

        var envrironment_text = "<br>"+environment + "<br>"

        document.write(envrironment_text);


        for (i = 0; i < config.advertisers[partner].hotel_id.length; i+locales_number) 
        { 

            for (j = 0; j < config.advertisers[partner].locales.length; j++) {

                var hotel_id = config.advertisers[partner].hotel_id[i];
                var locales = config.advertisers[partner].locales[j];

                link+= config.env[environment] + config.advertisers[partner].partner_id;
                link+= "/" + locales ;
                link+="/hotel/show?h[hotelId]=";
                link+=hotel_id+ "<br>";
                i++;
                if (i >= 10) { break; }
                }               
        }   
    document.write(link);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you must reset your link variable for each environment iteration. Yo can do this just after your document.write instruction.

```
document.write(link);
//variable reset
link = '';
```